# Is there any way to delay publishing and indexing when updating or creating items with the ItemService?

Tags: indexing, sitecore-services-client

I am syncing a significant amount of data into Sitecore from external systems on a fairly regular basis. To do this, I am utilizing the Sitecore ItemService.

The problem I'm currently facing is that publishing and indexing is being kicked off for every item being updated or created. I'm not sure, if it's affecting performance of the updates, but I'd really like to be able to run them once the syncing is complete.

I do know about using `Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext` to limit the publishing and indexing of items, but I don't know, if there is anything similar available for use with the ItemService.

Comment: Have you looked into the IndexCustodian to stop the indexing?

Comment: Can you make an API call before and after your sync to stop and start them?

Comment: @MichaelWest That may be an option, but a solution that didn't turn off indexing entirely would be ideal.

Comment: @ChrisAuer Absolutely. I would prefer to pause indexing for a specific item and its descendents as opposed to indexing entirely.